# How to track down the function that cause javascript error and save to log

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Now I use this code to save error log from user to database

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "call/savelog.php",
        data: {
            type : "bug\n" + version,
            message : 'Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+line
        }
    });
    return true;
};
```

when error occur on jquery or kineticjs function
if it was in javascript console I will got something like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined kinetic-v4.0.2.js:1386
Kinetic.Node.remove kinetic-v4.0.2.js:1386
Kinetic.Layer.remove kinetic-v4.0.2.js:3667
drawCountdown side_play.js:105
```

so I'll know error cause by my drawCountdown function in my javascript file side_play.js
but it appear like this in my error log

```
Error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
URL: https://myurl.com/js/kinetic-v4.0.2.js
Line Number: 1386
```

so I don't know which function that cause the error.
how to track down to the deepest function that cause error and save error log to database

Comment: The line number isn't specific enough?

Comment: edited question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your functions in try/catch statements and if an error occurs you can catch errors and then write them in file via server for example.

```
try {
  yourFunctionCallHere();
} catch (err) {
   var message = 'yourFunctionCallHere failed: ' + err.message;
   //now you can do smth with this error message, for example send an ajax request to the server...
}
```

Comment: I don't know which function will cause error. I have large amount of function should I wrap them all with try catch? Thank.

Comment: You can create an object and make your functions as methods of that object. Then, you can walk recursively through this methods and wrap them all in try catch. Here I wrote some generic example how you can achieve this goal - http://jsfiddle.net/DY6N6/

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using the window.onerror event, and that's good. I would not recommend inserting try catch everywhere in your code, I've talked to a lot of people who log JavaScript errors. And when you begin to insert try catch.

- There is a high risk that miss some places
- Normal development becomes harder because your try catches hide errors for developers, what you really want is try catch in production and no try catch in development

The people who I have spoken to who have inserted try catch on large projects, have really regretted it.

You could try my project [Muscula](http://muscula.com), It will try to fetch the javaScript source file, and show you the line of code that caused the error. This would solve your problem I think.

Also I auto-insert try catch in places where it's possible within reason (not everywhere), the rest of the errors are caught with window.onerror.

To use Muscula you just install a script, like Google Analytics, and you are logging errors. I would love for you to try it at let me know how it works for you. Right now Muscula is in open beta, and free to use. Used on approx. 4.000.000 pageviews every day.

Comment: I sold Muscula a year ago or more